# How to fetch the height and width of PDF/EPS files without using ImageMagick?

Tags: php, image, shell, pdf, eps

Is there any efficient way to grab the width and height information from PDF and EPS files?
I'm working with large files (50+ MB), which makes ImageMagick too slow for my needs.

Unfortunately PHP's builtin `imagesize()` function doesn't seem to work for these specific formats.

Answer (score 2):

Each **XObject** in PDF has its own **/Width** and **/Height** (original value before transformations). **Page**, **CropBox** and **MediaBox** also have Width and Height. So you can parse em. But you have not got predictable outcome, due to following transformations inside PDF BBoxes e.g. clipping, scaling ...

For EPS is the same situation, the post script is more readable (but you should apply all necessery transformations on object before get its size). Only the page  has the constant size ;)

```
... /HWResolution [600 600] /PageSize [842 595] ...
```